# Why can't I connect to my aws s3 bucket from pyspark running locally?

Tags: dataframe, amazon-s3, pyspark

I have a script that tries to load a pyspark data frame into aws s3. I have verified that public access is enabled in s3, and a colleague has managed to upload a file to the bucket from a script in data bricks. However, when I try to save a data frame to the bucket from a process runnign on my local machine, i get the following error:

```
Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Forbidden (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: 403 Forbidden;
```

I'm using pyspark version 3.2.1, and python 3.10. Here is my configuration:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql.types import StructField, StructType, IntegerType, StringType
import os
import sys

os.environ['PYSPARK_PYTHON'] = sys.executable
os.environ['PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON'] = sys.executable

conf = SparkConf().set('spark.jars.packages', 'org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.2.0')
conf.set('spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider', 'org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.AnonymousAWSCredentialsProvider')

sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sc.setSystemProperty('com.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4', 'true')

# Setting up S3 bucket credentials
ACCESS_KEY_ID = "xxxxxxx"
SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = "xxxxxxx"
AWS_BUCKET_NAME = "bucket_name"
DIRECTORY = "/directory /"

# hadoopConf = sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set('fs.s3a.access.key', ACCESS_KEY_ID)
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set('fs.s3a.secret.key', ENCODED_SECRET_KEY)
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set('fs.s3a.endpoint', 's3-eu-central-1.amazonaws.com')
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set('fs.s3a.impl', 'org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem')


spark = SparkSession(sc)
```

Here is the line of code that attempts to save the data frame:

```
result_dataframe.write.format("csv").option("header", "true").option("delimiter", "\t").mode("append").save(f"s3a://bucket_name/directory/{filename}.csv")
```

I can't figure out why my access is denied. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you using creds or not? You specify `AnonymousAWSCredentialsProvider` but then set creds? Delete one or the other (most likely, the anon cred provider) and try again. If the anon cred provider does not come last, any new cred providers will be ignored hence probably why you get access denied (as your creds are being ignored).

Comment: The default S3A auth provider chain should then kick in, the `SimpleAWSCredentialsProvider` should pick up on your `fs.s3a.*` config and allow you access to the bucket. Does that work?

Answer (score 0):

For AWS [Access Key + Secret Key] credentials, you don't have to provide any credentials provider class, as `org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.SimpleAWSCredentialsProvider` is taken as default. Source: [Hadoop-AWS module](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/index.html#Authentication_properties)

Try this:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.config('spark.jars.packages', 'org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.3.0').getOrCreate()
sc = spark.sparkContext
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.access.key", AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID)
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.secret.key", AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.endpoint", f"s3.{REGION_NAME}.amazonaws.com")
```

There's no need to encode the Secret Key. You can provide it as is.

You also need to set these extra JVM options in your Databricks Cluster before starting it:

```
spark.driver.extraJavaOptions -Dcom.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4=true
spark.executor.extraJavaOptions -Dcom.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4=true
```

[image]

Comment: do you have any justification for com.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4=true other than "other stack overflow examples did this?"

Comment: @stevel, I have edited my answer. The answer to your question is the same as my comments to this answer (also by me): https://stackoverflow.com/a/76227314/3546617