# Read Remote S3 File Using Databricks Connect

Tags: amazon-s3, pyspark, databricks, databricks-connect

I am trying to read a file in an S3 bucket using Spark through Databricks Connect.

This is the code that I am using,

```
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession


conf = SparkConf()
conf.set('spark.jars.packages', 'org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.3.0')
conf.set('spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key', access_key)
conf.set('spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key', secret_access_key)

 
spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf=conf).getOrCreate()

df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header",True).load('s3a://container/path/to/file.csv')

df.show()
```

This works completely fine when I execute it using a Docker container that I spin up, however, it fails with Databricks Connect with the following error,

```
pyspark.dbutils.ExecutionError: An error occurred while calling o48.ls.
: com.databricks.service.SparkServiceRemoteException: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: getFileStatus on com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Forbidden; request: HEAD Forbidden
    at shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AUtils.translateException(S3AUtils.java:244)
    at shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AUtils.translateException(S3AUtils.java:155)
    at shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.s3GetFileStatus(S3AFileSystem.java:2870)
    at shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.innerGetFileStatus(S3AFileSystem.java:2840)
    at shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.getFileStatus(S3AFileSystem.java:2779)
    at shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.innerListStatus(S3AFileSystem.java:2449)
    at shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.lambda$listStatus$11(S3AFileSystem.java:2428)
    at shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.Invoker.once(Invoker.java:118)
    at shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.Invoker.once(Invoker.java:112)
    at shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.listStatus(S3AFileSystem.java:2428)
    at com.databricks.service.SparkServiceImpl$.$anonfun$fileSystemOperation0$2(SparkServiceImpl.scala:617)
    at com.databricks.service.SparkServiceImpl$.withFileSystemExceptionHandler(SparkServiceImpl.scala:647)
    at com.databricks.service.SparkServiceImpl$.fileSystemOperation0(SparkServiceImpl.scala:617)
    at com.databricks.service.SparkServiceImpl$.$anonfun$fileSystemOperation$1(SparkServiceImpl.scala:184)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.$anonfun$recordOperation$4(UsageLogging.scala:431)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.$anonfun$withAttributionContext$1(UsageLogging.scala:239)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:62)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionContext(UsageLogging.scala:234)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionContext$(UsageLogging.scala:231)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.PublicDBLogging.withAttributionContext(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:19)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionTags(UsageLogging.scala:276)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionTags$(UsageLogging.scala:269)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.PublicDBLogging.withAttributionTags(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:19)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.recordOperation(UsageLogging.scala:412)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.recordOperation$(UsageLogging.scala:338)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.PublicDBLogging.recordOperation(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:19)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.PublicDBLogging.recordOperation0(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:56)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.recordOperation(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:131)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.UsageLogger.recordOperation(UsageLogger.scala:71)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.UsageLogger.recordOperation$(UsageLogger.scala:58)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.recordOperation(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:85)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.UsageLogging.recordOperation(UsageLogger.scala:401)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.UsageLogging.recordOperation$(UsageLogger.scala:380)
    at com.databricks.service.SparkServiceImpl$.recordOperation(SparkServiceImpl.scala:92)
    at com.databricks.service.SparkServiceImpl$.fileSystemOperation(SparkServiceImpl.scala:184)
    at com.databricks.service.SparkServiceRPCHandler.execute0(SparkServiceRPCHandler.scala:663)
    at com.databricks.service.SparkServiceRPCHandler.$anonfun$executeRPC0$1(SparkServiceRPCHandler.scala:451)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:62)
    at com.databricks.service.SparkServiceRPCHandler.executeRPC0(SparkServiceRPCHandler.scala:351)
    at com.databricks.service.SparkServiceRPCHandler$$anon$2.call(SparkServiceRPCHandler.scala:302)
    at com.databricks.service.SparkServiceRPCHandler$$anon$2.call(SparkServiceRPCHandler.scala:288)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at com.databricks.service.SparkServiceRPCHandler.$anonfun$executeRPC$1(SparkServiceRPCHandler.scala:338)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:62)
    at com.databricks.service.SparkServiceRPCHandler.executeRPC(SparkServiceRPCHandler.scala:315)
    at com.databricks.service.SparkServiceRPCServlet.doPost(SparkServiceRPCServer.scala:152)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:873)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:542)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:480)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:505)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:267)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:698)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:804)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Forbidden; request: HEAD
```

Note: I've scrubbed some information related to the path of my file in the above error thread.

Answer (score 0):

Your code

```
conf = SparkConf()
conf.set('spark.jars.packages', 'org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.3.0')
conf.set('spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key', access_key)
conf.set('spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key', secret_access_key)
```

works for local mode and not cluster mode.

Use this instead:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.config('spark.jars.packages', 'org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.3.0').getOrCreate()
sc = spark.sparkContext
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.access.key", AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID)
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.secret.key", AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.endpoint", f"s3.{REGION_NAME}.amazonaws.com")
```

This code sets the global Hadoop configurations for driver and executor nodes.

You also need to set these extra JVM options in your Databricks Cluster before starting it:

```
spark.driver.extraJavaOptions -Dcom.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4=true
spark.executor.extraJavaOptions -Dcom.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4=true
```

[image]

This works for me in Databricks and enables Spark to read/write from/to S3.

Comment: there is no need to set that system property  in hadoop >= 2.8. And there has never been been a need to specify fs.s3a.impl; it and the SimpleAWSCredentialsProvider options are set by default. please stop passing superstitions along. thanks

Comment: Thanks for the info @stevel. I have edited my answer accordingly. I had searched for a solution to this same problem that I encountered, for hours (both in SO and outside) and in all of them they had that property set and fs.s3a.impl added. Going by that, most of the internet is full of superstitions. But at least this answer is clean of anything of that sort, thanks to you :)

Comment: thanks...stack overflow seems to create spark code snippets copied and pasted into production code which simply generates support issues.